# Show data from dataset in CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If I do the following:

```
$('.js-element').attr("data-count", 2)
```

then I can show that value using CSS as:

```
.js-element:after {
    content: attr(data-count);
}
```

But if I do the following:

```
$('.js-element').data("count", 2)
```

then the same CSS code shows nothing.

As I understanding the difference is that in the first case I am just setting an attribute on the HTML element that I happen to prefix with data, while in the second case I am setting the dataset property of HTML element.

My questions are:

- Can one of the methods be considered better than the other?
- How can I get CSS to show values from the dataset?

Comment: you probably need to change the actual attribute rather than the data for the css to pick it up because the css will be using the attribute that is set on the element - it cannot see the dataset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As I understanding the difference is that in the first case I am just setting an attribute on the HTML element that I happen to prefix with data

Yes

> while in the second case I am setting the dataset property of HTML element.

No. You are setting jQuery's internal data store.

> Can one of the methods be considered better than the other?

That's subjective

> How can I get CSS to show values from the dataset?

Set the dataset value (`document.querySelector('.js-element').dataset.count = 2`), which will map onto the attribute automatically.

Answer (score 1):

1. Subjective to the use-case and the limitations.

   `element.dataset` - It contains only the custom `data-*` attributes.

   `jQuery's data()` - Its functionality defers based on the version used. Upto version 1.4.3, `.data()` returns only the custom arbitrary values set via `.data(key, value)`. jQuery versions from 1.4.4, it returns both the `dataset` and values set via `.data(key, value)` as a single object. Refer [jQuery .data() docs](https://api.jquery.com/data/) for more info.

   Limitation : `jQuery's data()` can't set values on `object`, `embed` and `applet` elements but those can have `dataset`.
2. The `dataset` values are taken from the HTML DOM Element or can be set dynamically via javascript/jquery or any other means.

```js
var elem = document.querySelector("#para");
setTimeout(function(){
    elem.dataset.before="Modified Before Content";
    elem.dataset.after="Modified After Content";
},1000);
```

```css
p::before
{
    content : attr(data-before)
}
p::after
{
    content : attr(data-after)
}
```

```html
<p id="para" data-before="Before Content" data-after="After Content">
  <br>
  Middle
  <br>
</p>
```

[CSS Access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#CSS_access) to the element's dataset is limited to pseudo-elements, though it can be applied to all elements as per [W3 Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#attr-notation). But it not has been implemented by all major browsers.